# Angular CLI error messege in ng --version command

Tags: angular-cli

I already installed Angular, but in visual studio code there is an error message as shown below, when loading the command `ng --version`.

How can I fix this problem?

Error:
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key
'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied. To change the execution policy
for the default (LocalMachine) scope, start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option. To change the execution
policy for the current user, run "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser".
At line:1 char:1

- Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], UnauthorizedAccessException
  ```

PS C:\angularsample\dummyapp> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSignedSet-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSignedvvv
"Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicyScope". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name RemoteSignedvvv to a valid enumerator
name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
Process, CurrentUser, LocalMachine, UserPolicy, MachinePolicy"
At line:1 char:53

- Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSignedSet-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSignedvvv
- ```
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand

PS C:\angularsample\dummyapp> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key
'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied. To change the execution policy
for the default (LocalMachine) scope, start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option. To change the execution
policy for the current user, run "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser".
At line:1 char:1

- Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
  ```

[image]

[error_angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UGME.png)

Comment: Where is the error message?

Comment: Install angular in that path and try version command

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please show text (including error messages) as formatted text in your question, instead of using a screenshot. See why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question.